# Using a different serialization method for a particular field based on some condition

Tags: rust, serde

I am working on library. It was encoding an object

```rust
pub struct obj {
    pub appliance_id: u32,
    pub last: bool,
    pub path: PathBuf,
}
```

And, previously the encoding for invalid utf-8 was not handled. So, I have written a separate method to serialize path

```rust
pub fn serialize<S>(p: &Arc<PathBuf>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let b = p.as_os_str().as_bytes();
    serializer.serialize_bytes(b)
}
```

What I want is that if the path is valid utf-8 than it should serialize with default serializer for `PathBuf`, which is by converting it to `str` and than serialize it. And, In case of invalid utf-8 it should fallback to the new method written for serialize path.
And same should work for deserializer.

Comment: What serialization format are you using? What you describe can only work for self-describing formats. It would also be nice if you could explain _why_ you want the behaviour you describe, i.e what the actual problem you are solving is.

Comment: is [that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=880306aa936b556b2f1b4770e0f1fcbc) what you are trying to archive? I don't really get what you are trying to archive

Comment: Yes @Bamontan. This should work. But how we will handle deserialization for this serialization?

Comment: @Bamontan The lossy conversion kind of defeats the whole point of having two different serialization modes. If you are ok with a lossy conversion, you can simply always use that, and always serialize as a string. Otherwise, you should use `p.as_os_str().as_bytes()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah that's what I tought too, but I wasn't able to find how to get a byte view on the OsString. That's why I did'nt put it as answer, I was just asking if that was the intent. Looking at the response of Caesar I found out about the ffi needed to make it work, and I wouldn't able to use it anyway cause I run windows. But yeah I should have made a comment about it.

Comment: @Bamontan The correct conversion from `PathBuf` to `&[u8]` hass been in this question all along, so I thought you intentionally changed this to the lossy conversion for some reason.

Comment: @Bamontan Well, an [equivalent](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.encode_wide) method exists for windows, but you'll get potentially invalid utf16. If that stays on windows, you can use it just fine, but I don't think there's a sane method for converting invalid utf16 to utf8. This is akin to the "Makefile problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll assume that you're fine with this only working on `cfg(unix)`, since you're using `OsStrExt::as_bytes`. Accessing the content of non-utf8 `PathBuf`s is tricky in the general case.

The serialization function was already mostly given by @Bamontan:

```rust
fn serialize<S>(p: &PathBuf, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    if let Some(utf8) = p.to_str() {
        serializer.serialize_str(utf8)
    } else {
        serializer.serialize_bytes(p.as_os_str().as_bytes())
    }
}
```

deserialization is a bit more involved, since you'll need a visitor that can handle both strings and byte arrays:

```rust
fn deserialize<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<PathBuf, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct V;
    impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for V {
        type Value = PathBuf;
        
        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
            write!(formatter, "a string or array of bytes")
        }

        fn visit_str<E>(self, s: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
        where
            E: serde::de::Error,
        {
            Ok(s.into())
        }
        fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
        where
            A: SeqAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut res = vec![];
            while let Some(b) = seq.next_element::<u8>()? {
                res.push(b);
            }
            Ok(OsString::from_vec(res).into())
        }
    }
    d.deserialize_any(V)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6aa9d64ff6c48c2e4459f37325693203)
This will of course only work if your serialized format is self-describing like JSON, i.e. it must be ok to use `deserialize_any` and let serde figure out whether there's a list or a string. If that isn't the case, you'll need a type tag or similar.

There may be easier ways of solving this (deserialize to `JsonValue` first and convert), and possibly also more elegant ways (maybe deserialize to an `Either<Vec<u8>, String>` and convert), but this should get you started.